# Simplify Exist Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, subquery, having-clause

How can I simplify the below query to return field2 only if there exist records with key_id ECRU and MTR.

```
SELECT
    z.field2
FROM
    mytable z
WHERE
        z.key_id = 'ECRU'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            mytable
        WHERE
                key_id = 'MTR'
            AND field2 = z.field2
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group by` and `having`:

```
select field2
from mytable
where key_id in ('ECRU', 'MTR')
group by field2
having count(*) = 2
```

This assumes no duplicate `(field2, key_id)`. Otherwise, you need to slightly change the `having` clause:

```
having count(distinct key_id) = 2
```

Comment: This needs to be an AND operation and there can be other key values other than the ones specified.

Comment: @FurqanShaikh but in the question there's no other values mentioned. This solves what you already asked.

Comment: I think using intersect may simplify this.
SELECT field2
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  key_id = 'ECRU'
INTERSECT
SELECT field2
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  key_id = 'MTR'

will this have any difference on performance than the previous correlated query?